# Creating a Heatmap Raster GeoTIFF in R

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, heat-map, kernel-density

Is there a way to create a raster heatmap (aka 2d kernel density) from point data in R which can then be exported as a geoTIFF file?

I'm able to create a heatmap in R easily using ggplot2's geom_density_2d, but as far as I am aware this does not in any way allow me to export the resulting heatmap as a geoTIFF raster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make some data so we have a reproducible example:

```
> set.seed(123); xy = cbind(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000))
```

Use `kde2d` from `MASS`. Pick `h` for a nice smooth map, pick `n` for the resolution:

```
> library(MASS)
> k = kde2d(xy[,1],xy[,2],h=.4,n=100)

> library(raster)
> r = raster(k)
> plot(r)
```

[image]

Which you can write to a geoTIFF:

```
> writeRaster(r,"k.tiff")
```

Comment: How can you control the resolution across different points data sets? Or, How can I generate a raster with the same dimensions to compare different rasters?

Comment: You should be able to do this by calling `kde2d` with the correct `lims` and `n` parameters. If you want more specifics work it up into a full question with example rasters and if you tag it with "r" I'll see it.

Comment: Oh you already did! I see it!