# How to interpret Kernel Density Maps

Tags: raster, r, kernel-density

- In [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/250147/18535) example, kernel density maps are created.
- In [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389610/18535)
  example, it is shown how to create comparable kernel density raster
  maps

Now I would like to understand what are the units of kernel density maps in R.

?kde2d says:

> Two-Dimensional Kernel Density Estimation: Two-dimensional kernel
> density estimation with an axis-aligned bivariate normal kernel,
> evaluated on a square grid.
>
> It returns a list of three components. x, y The x and y coordinates of
> the grid points, vectors of length n.
>
> z  An n[1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/250147/18535) by n[2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389610/18535) matrix of the estimated density: rows correspond to
> the value of x, columns to the value of y.

I have seen some definitions, for instance from [ESRI](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-kernel-density-works.htm), but at the end, I have never understood what are the correct units for the legend.

```
library(MASS)
library(raster)
set.seed(123); 

pp <- rnorm(100)
k = kde2d(
  x = rnorm(100) - 43,
  y = rnorm(100) - 23, 
  h=0.2 , 
  n=1000, 
  lims = c(c(-43,-42), 
           c(-23, -22)))
rk <- raster(k)

rk2 <- projectRaster(from = rk, crs = "+init=epsg:31983")

res(rk)
#[1] 0.001001001 0.001001001
res(rk/area(rk))
#[1] 0.001001001 0.001001001
res(rk2)
#[1] 103 111


par(mfrow =c(1,3))
plot(
  rk, 
  main = "raster lat long", 
  horizontal = TRUE, 
  legend.args = list(text='units')
)
plot(
  rk/area(rk), 
  main = "raster lat long / raster area(km2)", 
  horizontal = TRUE, 
  legend.args = list(text='units')
)
plot(rk2, 
     main = "raster UTM (epsg 31983)", 
     horizontal = TRUE, 
     legend.args = list(text='units')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output from `kde2d` is a *density* and like a probability density it integrates over the space to one.

For example, lets take 100 points:

```
> xy = cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
```

and compute the density over a large range relative to the points:

```
> k1 = kde2d(xy[,1],xy[,2],n=100,lims=c(-4,4,-4,4))
```

Now to integrate the density you multiply the value by the cell area and sum that up:

```
> sum(k1$z) * ( diff(k1$x)[1]*diff(k1$y)[1])
[1] 0.9999767
```

which is very close to one. If we do it with double the number of points:

```
> xy2 = cbind(rnorm(200),rnorm(200))
> k2 = kde2d(xy2[,1],xy2[,2],n=100,lims=c(-4,4,-4,4))
> image(k2)
> sum(k2$z) * ( diff(k2$x)[1]*diff(k2$y)[1])
[1] 0.9999815
```

We still get a number close to one.

If you want to convert to *intensity*, or points per unit area, multiply Z by the number of points you started with:

```
> k2$z = k2$z * nrow(xy2)
```

and now the output integrates to the number of points:

```
> sum(k2$z) * ( diff(k2$x)[1]*diff(k2$y)[1])
[1] 199.9963
>
```

That assumes equal area cell sizes, because `kde2d` assumes that in order to make sure the output is a density. I don't think that you can then modify the values based on the coordinate system resulting in non-equal area cells, so if your data is lat-long, you need to project *the points* to a cartesian coordinate system before using `kde2d` on a grid based on that. If you need lat-long grid then you have to transform that grid to lat-long.